# Change logo position in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-template, joomla3.2

I'e been using joomla default template: Protostar. From template manager I set a logo and it appears at the left top of each page. How can I shift the logo 100px right?

I'm running joomla 3.2.1 in localhost.

Comment: @CTravel I can't figure out what portion of the css file needs to be changed.

Comment: try finding it out with the developertool from your browser, you can select te element and it will give you the class of id name and probably the row of the css file that you need to change..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the following file:

```
root/templates/protostar/css/template.css
```

Search for the logo and edit or add the following:

```
#logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}
```

or on line **6936**, you will find the `.site-title { }` block, which you can replace with the following:

```
.site-title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 100px;
    line-height: 48px;
    position: relative;
}
```

In future, start getting used to your browser console and start inspecting elements. If you're using Firefox, then I would recommend using Firebug.

Comment: The only thing I would say is that you should never edit the css directly any more, you should always edit the less and recompile, which is very easy in the template manager at this point.